# componentDidMount not being called for any of my components

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router

I am using Meteor with React. I am using Kadira flowrouter-ssr as my router.

It's so weird. None of my components get their `componentDidMount()` called.

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990133/react-componentdidmount-not-firing/34007774) which seems like the same issue.

I think React only uses `getInitialState()` & `render()` to compile to create the html.

It's weird because it was working before and I deployed a new version, didn't update anything and it stopped working. All I did was add a couple of components.

It works on my local machine so I am sure it's something to do with how it's being compiled.

Other than that I am blank. I have no idea what's up with this.

Comment: Are you rendering it in a browser or in node.js? Because componentDidMount is called only on client side.

Comment: I'm rendering it in my browser. Works perfectly in dev mode. Problem occurs when i deploy it on a server

Comment: Can you share some code ? What happens when you push F12 and open the JS console ?