# React isomorphic client side DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

My server is using `renderToString()` to render my react router based app.

```
// isomorphic route
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {

  let history = useQueries(createMemoryHistory)();
  // let store = configureStore();
  let routes = createRoutes(history);
  let location = history.createLocation(req.url);

  match({routes, location}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    } else if (renderProps) {
      let content = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />);
      res.render('main', {content: content});
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found')
    }
  });
});
```

The createRoutes file

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import HomeView from './views/HomeView'
import VideoView from './views/VideoView'

export default (history) => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={HomeView}></Route>
      <Route path="/v/:id" component={VideoView}></Route>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Since I am using `RouterContext` on the server, my question is how do I wire up the client side to **allow react's own events to be accessible and "fireable" again on the client side**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Router, hashHistory} from 'react-router';  
import createRoutes from '../2-shared/routes';

ReactDom.render(// RouterContext??, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I am not really sure what to do here in terms of enabling the client side to listen to lifecycle events from the component like `componentDidMount()` currently my `console.log`'s are all going to the server, and nothing is being listened to on the client.

Having a similar issue to [react componentDidMount not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990133/react-componentdidmount-not-firing)

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to have your views load the JS on the client side, also.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are developing an *isomorphic* app, you would load JS on both client and server side. Client side will re-render the app and, if everything is ok, will not even touch DOM because there will be no updates. However, it will wire all your event listeners properly.

`componentDidMount` will never fire on the server side because it never really does get mounted. `componentWillMount` will fire normally on server, though.