# Reactjs not updating anything

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i have tried disabling cache but it does not work 
my Code

```
componentDidMount = () => {


  alert("hello")


  }
```

i dont get the alert today anything else is not updating even

Comment: This code is not enough to understand your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react componentDidMount not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990133/react-componentdidmount-not-firing)

Answer (score -1):

For displaying alerts in React Native, you need to use the native [`Alert API`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html#alert), as the browser-defined `alert` is not supported:

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

componentDidMount = () => {
    Alert.alert("hello")
}
```

Comment: but it worked previously and <h1>  tags are alsop not updating & nothing else

Comment: With only this code I am afraid I can't provide more of an answer.

Answer (score -2):

I tried this

```html
 componentWillMount() {
       
       alert("hello")
   }
```

and this worked

Comment: Please provide further details about your object. Lets see and resolve this issue